# OpenCV calibrateCamera - MSFT LifeCam 3000 HD

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

I am trying to use the OpenCV calibrateCamera function to calibrate my MSFT LifeCam 3000 HD webcam.  In order to do that, I understand that need to know fx and fy (the focal lengths of both the x and y axes).  However, I am having a tough time finding that information out.

The only technical data from the spec sheet appears to be:

1. "fixed focus from 0.3 to 1.5mm";
2. "Field of View - 68.5 deg diagonal field of view".

The camera does have a 16:9 aspect ratio.

There is no information about the size of the sensor, manufacturer, etc.
I even tore one of these cameras down but the sensor is tiny and there are no markings on the chip itself.

I am following [this](http://www.aishack.in/2010/07/calibrating-undistorting-with-opencv-in-c-oh-yeah/) example for the calibration process, which I have seen recommended.

Am I doing this right? Any idea on how to get the information?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You might look into [`cv::initCameraMatrix2D()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#initcameramatrix2d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to know fx and fy. The calibrateCamera() does that for you. I suggest you try this tutorial http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html